# How can i get the value of a html select element inside a repeater control on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater with select html inside the item template.

I could not use dropdown list as it does not support  so i had to build select with  inside a repeater.

On button click i want get the value of the selected item.

the  inside the repeater does not have runat=server.

How can i do this?

Comment: You can most certainly place a DropDownList inside of an ItemTemplate.  Will providing you information on how to do that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can acces via `Request.Form["DROPNAME"]`